# How to wrap (prefix & suffix) all values in a column with a string?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with about 1000 rows in it.

```
id column
1  apple
2  banana
...
etc
```

I need a MySQL query (UpdatE) to wrap (prefix & suffix) all values in a column with a specific string, let's say "_", so I am expecting a result:

```
id column
1  _apple_
2  _banana_
...
etc
```

How to do that? Please, advice.

Answer (score 28):

```
update table
set column = concat('_', column, '_');
```